# Main calling main

Tags: c

```
{
 static int i=5;
 if(--i)
  {
   main(); 
   printf("%d ",i);
  }
}
```

The output of this program is `0 0 0 0`.

Shouldn't this program show compiler error? What am I missing here?

Comment: Isn't this just basic recursion...?

Comment: C++ forbids calling main. C allows it. Note that `i` has iterated all the way to 0 before any printing is done. Maybe that is your confusion.

Comment: This is a code fragment, not a program. If you added `#include <stdio.h>` and `int main(void)`, it would be a program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I +1 your question because in my 15 years of programming I have never thought of recursively calling main()!

Now regarding your question, it compiles because main() is just a function like any other function in the code. The only special thing about it is that the linker expects to see a main() in the code and a call to main() is automatically inserted inside the executable. (I think you can even use linker switches to define a different startup function name).

But other than that, it's a normal function.

Comment: "in my 15 years of programming I have never thought of recursively calling on main()" and I hope you won't start because you saw this. I've seen it used once to good effect: a code obfuscation entry used it to allocate memory in a program which contained only a single semicolon. Also this is forbidden explicitly in C++.

Comment: @Dave - don't worry, I won't. But I did start using goto here and there because all the standards say not to, so they actually point out that this command exists, and if it exists I need to check it out... And I find it quite useful in cases mentioned in K&R book, like resources deallocation within a function (something like an exception handling).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about `main` that means that you can't use it in your program, but it's not recommended because it obfuscates your code. (This terrifying code that won a contest for being so hard to read calls it's own main, and it compiles without warning: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/tball/papers/xmasgift/)

If you're confused about the flow of your program, consider switching the `main` and the `printf`

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
  static int i=5;
  if(--i)
  {
    printf("%d ",i);
    main(); 
  }    
}
```

The output is `4 3 2 1`

Edit: This code properly uses `int main(void)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  static int i=5;
  if(--i)
  {
    printf("%d ",i);
    main(); 
  }

  return 0    
}
```

Comment: It's `int main(void)`, *not* `void main()`. If you learned `void main()` from something that purports to be a C book, please let us know which book it is so we warn people away from it. (Yes, `void main()` can be valid in some limited circumstances, but "it's wrong" is close enough for most purposes.)

Comment: Considering that we're recursively calling `main` style has kinda gone out the window. In the original code, there is no return value. But I'll edit my response anyways. I agree that it's incorrect and sometimes it causes failures. Here's a little more info on `void main(void)` for those who care: http://c-faq.com/ansi/voidmain.html

Comment: No, regardless of whether you're calling `main` recursively or not, a program with `void main()` has *undefined behavior* unless the current implementation explicitly permits it. There is no good reason to use `void main()` unless you're programming for an embedded system that specifically requires it. And there's no point in keeping your original almost-certainly-incorrect code in the answer.

Comment: I apologize, I was unclear. I admit `void main()` is incorrect and your above comment is completely correct. I was merely trying to match the style of the original question. I also admit a little bit of laziness because I have written a fair bit of embedded code on a legacy processor that required `void main(void)` but you are indeed correct and my included link backs you up.

Comment: Cool -- though I'm not quite sure what you mean about the style of the original question, which doesn't even declare `main` -- and would be perfectly valid code with the addition of `#include <stdio.h>` and `int main(void)`.

Comment: No, as of C99 reaching the closing `}` at the end of `main` is equivalent to executing `return 0;`. (C++ has always (I think) had the same rule.)