# Why Output is 0000 and How?

Tags: c

I executed this program and am unable to understand why the output is "0" four times. Can anybody help me understand how it works?  I do not understand why "printf" executes when the condition fails and why it executes four times.

```c
int main() 
{
    static int i=5; 
    if(--i)
    {
        main(); 
        printf("%d ",i);
    }
}
```

Comment: please you proper indentation and complete words

Comment: actually its an exact duplicate

Comment: @niko hehe.. It's been asked many times on SO itself :) Let me find some more...People need to improve googlefu skills!

Comment: Some here:
1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964387/why-does-this-program-not-run-infinitely

2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785765/values-obtained-in-case-of-a-recursive-function

3) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518915/main-calling-main

Comment: Also note in `c++` the standard dictates you should *not* call `main()` within your program.  Valid in `c` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main function prints 4 times 0 because the printf statement occurs after the recursive call and `i` is a static variable. A static variable is initialised only once and it is not destroyed after the function terminates since it is not allocated into the function stack.
As result, the value of `i` used by the `printf` is always 0 as `i` is decremented each time `main` is called and the first `printf` function is executed after the deepest function has returned because `i=0`.

To better understand this solution, let's look at the stack call :

```
main() i=5 (First call)  
      if(4) // True
      main() (Second call) 
        if(3) // True
        main() (Third  call)
          if(2) // True
            main() (Forth call) 
               if(1) // True
                 main() (Fifth call)
                    if(0) //False End recursion No print because the condition is false
                 return
                print(i) // 0 (Forth Call)
            print(i) // 0 (Third  call)
         printf(i) // 0  (Second call) 
      print(i) // 0 (First call)
```

The `main` is called 5 times but the application prints 4 zeros because the the last call does not print anything as the `if` condition is false.

Comment: I am understanding evrything that i is static so its initialized one time in program but everytime main() is called before printf and in last condition is false so we will not enter into if block Then how printf is executing?

Comment: I have update my answer. Let me know if it is more clear now

Comment: Yes Thank You Sir But Can You Explain Me One More Thing If We Remove Static Keyword Then Why Its Become Infinite Means Stackoverflow call Acording To Me If We Remove Only static keywords Then It Should Print 1234

Comment: If you remove `static` from the `i`, the function never reaches the end of the recursion because for each function call i=5, therefore the if is always true and another call to main is made.

Comment: Oh I Forgot Property Of Static. Ok Thank You

Answer (score 3):

`i` is *static* so it is initialized only once. Every time you call `main` it is decremented when `i == 1` then the `*if* statement condition will be *false* here:

```
if(--i)
```

the recursion will stop and `i` will be `0`, the recursion will then unwind and the program will print four `0`s.

For completeness sake, the draft C99 standard section `6.2.4` *Storage durations of objects* paragraph *3* says(*emphasis mine*):

> An object whose identifier is declared with external or internal linkage, or with the
>   storage-class **specifier static** has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire
>   execution of the program and its stored **value is initialized only once, prior to program
>   startup**.

Comment: I am understanding evrything that i is static so its initialized one time in program but am still unable to understand printf is not getting a chance to execute still it is printing the value how?

Comment: @RaaJivYadav before each `printf` there is a recursive call to `main` and so the first `printf` won't be reached until the recursion ends which will happen when `i == 1`.

Comment: Yes before printf there Is Recursive call to main So Control will reach to main Then Again It Wil Enter to if Condition then again control wil reach to main before printf and when i==1 then if(--i) wil look like if(0) then control wil not enter to if condition and program wil end Then How It is Posible To Executing The printf

Comment: @RaaJivYadav when the code falls off the end of `main` it will return to the previous invocation of `main` and continue to execute where it left off which was right before `printf` and it will do that for each level of recursion in this case `4` levels.